# Calculate the inductance voltage from its current time function

Tags: transient

I have a solution for the following exercise, but I'm not sure if it's a good one.

This is the current time function of the inductance:

$$i(t) = 2-2e^{-t/T}\text{ (A)}$$
$$L = 10\text{ mH}$$
$$T = 2\text{ ms}$$

Calculate the inductance voltage at \$t = 3\text{ ms}\$.

This is my solution:

$$UL = L \times \frac{di(t)}{dt}$$
$$UL(t) =  10\text{ mH}$$
$$UL(t) = 10 \times e^{-t/t}$$
$$UL(t=3\text{ ms}) = 10 \times e^{-3/2} = 2.23\text{ V}$$

Is it right?

Comment: The answer looks correct. The second line of the equation should be: UL(t)=10mH * di(t)/dt.

Comment: Thanks, but I missed 10^-3 from the inductance because it's 10 mH, so correctly:

UL(t= 3ms) = 10*10^-3 * e^-3/2 = 2.23 mV

Comment: No, that is incorrect. It should be 2.23 because T = 2ms, in the milli scale too.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how the reactance dimension disappear? 
It's 10 mH, why can we write only 10 instead of 10*10^-3?

Comment: The milli from the inductor gets cancelled out by the milli from the T. See the answer given by Jan Eerland below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, notice that we know that:

$$\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\text{L}\text{I}_\text{L}'\left(t\right)\tag1$$

So, when:

$$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=2\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\right)\tag2$$

We get:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{L}'\left(t\right)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(2\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\right)\right)\\
\\
&=2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(1\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\right)\right)\\
\\
&=2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(1\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(1\right)+\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(t\right)\right)\\
\\
&=2\left(0+\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)\cdot1\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{2}{\text{T}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{T}}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\tag3
$$

So, we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{L}\left(3\cdot10^{-3}\right)=10\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\frac{2}{2\cdot10^{-3}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{3\cdot10^{-3}}{2\cdot10^{-3}}\right)=\frac{10}{\exp\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\approx2.2313\space\text{V}\tag4$$

> So, you're right!